# Passing Context of an Activity to another Activity in Android

Tags: android

Consider I have an Activity "ProductsActivity" and "AddItemsActvity" , I need the Context of ProductsActivity in AddItemsActvity.
Are there any suggestions or methods to pass Context among activities in android.

Comment: what is your goal using the other activities context? is it to reference a method/variable declared in that activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Context of ProductsActivity" is actually the instance of ProductsActivity (Activity is derived from Context). So what you want is to pass a reference of ProductsActivity to AddItemsActivity.

This is not a good idea, as your ProductsActivity can get stopped and destroyed while your AddItemsActivity is running. You usually don't want to pass Activity pointers around.